# Knowledge Article Not Copying Related Custom Object Record when in Draft Mode

Tags: knowledge, lightning-knowledge

I am using Lightning Knowledge and I have a custom object linked with (Lookup) to Knowledge object. Now when I edit one published article as "Edit as draft", what I seeing is that not the related records from the custom object is getting copied to the new version. It is still linked with the previous version. DO you know is this the normal behavior or can we have some customization to copy the related records to the new version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the standard behavior

> Child objects are linked to the knowledge article version.

You can maintain consistency by

1. store Knowledge Article Id(Formula field) on the child object
2. A trigger on Knowledge Article which transfers all the child records to the latest version of the article(Knowledge_kav has a IsLatestVersion field).

Answer (score 2):

We've had discussions with Salesforce and checked with the product team about this and they let us know this is by design and **will not be changing.** The reason for that has to do with the Knowledge data model and how the records are linked. It's noted in the [release notes for Summer '19](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_knowledge_lookups.htm) how the lookup is linked to the *version* object only.

You didn't mention this, but there's also the risk of leaving your related objects with no lookup value when you just *publish* the article (as that deletes the version in the data model since it's getting *replaced* as the current version).

[image]

> Keep in mind that lookups to Knowledge link to a specific article
>   version. If you publish an article and don’t use the option to Publish
>   as new version, the previously published version is deleted.

You can get around this by always doing **"Publish as new version"** anywhere you publish (users in UI and automation in code, approvals, etc).

This doesn't necessarily solve your *specific* issue as "edit as draft" will still not carry over the related records. However, that is by design and won't be changing in the near term. You'd have to look at custom options (trigger) to re-parent the lookup to the latest version if you need it on the latest version always.